# Solving LP with two $L_1$ inequality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization

Is there a "fast" way to solve the following  LP formulation with the following constraints:
$$ \max_{\mathbf{f}} \mathbf{f}'.\mathbf{g} \\
\mathbf{1}'\mathbf{f}=1\\
\|\mathbf{f}-\mathbf{h}\|_1\le \epsilon_1\\
\|\mathbf{f}-\mathbf{k}\|_1\le \epsilon_2$$

$\mathbf{g}, \mathbf{h}, \mathbf{k}, \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$, are known. $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector and could be large.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "fast"? This is a trivial model for a general purpose convex optimization framework to solve. In fact, even a linear programming engine can handle it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Assume $|\mathbf{f}|=10$. The way I am representing the inequality constraints for feeding them to a solver (e.g., matlab linprog) is to create a matrix of $2^{11}$ for the inequalities. Using matlab (default setting), as $|\mathbf{f}|$ gets larger, the solution takes a longer time that I wanted. Also, I am recalculating the optimization several times. So, the overall calculation is time-consuming. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a fast way or a heuristic to get the results faster.

Comment: Whoa, that's not the way to do it. Hold on. I will post an answer.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have `linprog`, let's start there. Your challenge is to reformulate into an LP that is as compact as possible. Enumerating the vertices as you are doing is *not* the way to go about it. Instead, you want to define vector variables $p$, $q$, and do this:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & g^T f \\
\text{subject to} & \vec{1}^T f = 1 \\
                  & \vec{1}^T p = \epsilon_1 \\
                  & \vec{1}^T q = \epsilon_2 \\
                  & - p \preceq f - h \preceq p \\
                  & - q \preceq f - k \preceq q
\end{array}$$
Do you see what's happening here? We are ensuring that $|f_i-h_i|\leq p_i$ and $|f_i-k_i|\leq q_i$, so that $\sum_i p_i$ bounds $\|f-h\|_1$ and $\sum_i q_i$ bounds $\|f-k\|_1$. This is a very standard transformation to convert the $\ell_1$ norm to an LP-compatible form. Of course, now you need to construct the inputs to `linprog` by stacking the equality constraint and inequality constraint coefficients into matrices. That can get messy.

Now, if you had my software [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx), it would be even easier. You just type this in, and let it take care of the messy transformations under the hood.

```
cvx_begin
    variable f(n)
    maximize( g' * f )
    subject to
        sum(f) == 1
        norm(f-h,1) <= epsilon1
        norm(f-k,1) <= epsilon2
cvx_end
```

Do what is fastest for *you* first, to see if you like the numerical results you're getting. If you do like the results, but you still need more speed, then you'll probably want to hand-code your model for input to a high-performance LP solver like Gurobi, MOSEK, or CPLEX.

Comment: Thanks! I will try both of them. Suppose I use `linprog` for now. One thing that I am still confused is how to encode $p$ and $q$ as variables in `linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,x0)`. Where would they be placed as input arguments to `linprog`? My thought was only $f$ includes the variables!

Comment: Yes, that's the difficulty. Basically, `linprog` sees a length-$3n$ variable vector `[f;p;q]`, so you have to build the coefficient matrices `f`, `A`, `b`, `Aeq`, and `beq`, etc. so that they produce the desired model. It's kind of a pain to do that, frankly, which is one reason why CVX was invented.

Comment: Just making sure: is the length of $b$ equal to $4n$ (taking care of each inequality), using `linprog`?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! Likewise, you have three equations.

Comment: Just to be consistent, I think in the CVX code `minimize` should be `maximize`. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're right, I will edit.

Comment: I love your answer! My code runs much faster now. I will try CVX too.